# Update android app on playstore?

Tags: android, google-play, publishing

I am providing the detailed reply from Google for app violation

Below is the content got from Google when i tried to update my application which is in prod for the past 1.5 years kindly help me with any solution thanks in advance

REASON FOR REMOVAL: Violation of the spam provisions of the Content Policy. Please refer to the keyword spam policy help article for more information.

Your title and/or description must not attempt to impersonate or leverage another popular product without permission.
Do not engage in "keyword stuffing" by loading app descriptions with keywords out of context.
Do not use irrelevant, misleading, or excessive keywords in apps descriptions, titles, or metadata.
This particular app has been disabled as a policy strike. If your developer account is still in good standing, you may revise and upload a policy compliant version of this application as a new package name.

This notification also serves as notice for remaining, unsuspended violations in your catalog, and you may avoid further app suspensions by immediately unpublishing any apps in violation of (but not limited to) the above policy. Once you have resolved any existing violations, you may republish the app(s) at will. Before publishing applications, please ensure your apps’ compliance with the Developer Distribution Agreement and Content Policy.

All violations are tracked. Serious or repeated violations of any nature will result in the termination of your developer account, and investigation and possible termination of related Google accounts. If your account is terminated, payments will cease and Google may recover the proceeds of any past sales and the cost of any associated fees (such as chargebacks and payment transaction fees) from you.

If you feel we have made this determination in error, you can visit the Google Play Help Center article for additional information regarding this removal.

The Google Play Team
--------------------------------------------
Regards
Gopi.cs

Comment: You need to sort this out with the people that actually can help you with this, i.e. the Google Play team.

Comment: I am just asking what might the problem to produce this issue the issue is after 3 major updates

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Google Play support.

Answer (score 1):

read over the policy stated in the REASON FOR REMOVAL and try to follow the best practice that they state : https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2985717?hl=en